# Date validator is not failing when it should

Tags: java, date

I have a custom validator in my spring boot aplication, the validator is called, because I set a breakpoint and it stops.

The problem is the date validator is not working.

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMYYYY"); 

@Override
public boolean isValid(String date, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(date == null) {
        return true;
    }
    try {
        DATE_FORMAT.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm testing it with an invalid date 785454, but it does not go to the exception.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What values does parse returns?

Comment: 1. Use `java.time.*` instead; 2. Did you really mean to use `YYYY` (Week year) or did you really mean `yyyy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. fix pattern:   `SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy")`
2. it add up the months:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy").parse("122000"); = Fri Dec 01 00:00:00 CET 2000
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy").parse("132000"); = Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2001
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy").parse("785454"); = Fri Jun 01 00:00:00 CEST 5460
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyy").parse("015454"); = Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 5454
```

3. the only exception you'll have to expect is `ParseException - if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed.` ([see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)))

And the right solution (from comment):
`setLenient`[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) and except

Comment: thanks! Based on your reply i saw that i needed DATE_FORMAT.setLenient(false); and update the exception to the ParseException one, it is working now

Answer (score 0):

From the docs `Throws: NullPointerException - if text or pos is null.`

It looks like the parse method throws exception only if the value given is null.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html